# Ansible newline in jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, newline

I am trying to create docker-compose config with Ansible. I am using Jinja2 template for this.

Here is part of jinja template code:

```
    image: {% if version == "4.2" %}appname:4.2.0{% elif version == "4.0.5" %}dockerhub2:10000/appname:4.0.5{% else %}dockerhub2:10000/appname3:3.0.14{%  endif %}
    container_name: {{ dir }}
```

What I expect to see:

```
    image: dockerhub2:10000/appname3:3.0.14
    container_name: name
```

What I really see:

```
    image: dockerhub2:10000/appname3:3.0.14    container_name: name
```

How can I describe a newline here?

Comment: I'm surprised by that behavior, but it appears inserting a newline after the final `%}` will do what you want, as would moving that expression to a `image: {{ "appname:4.2.0" if version == "4.2" else ... }}` style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put *endif* on the next line. Quoting from [Whitespace Control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#whitespace-control)

> *"a single trailing newline is stripped if present"*

```yaml
    image: {% if version == "4.2" %}appname:4.2.0{% elif version == "4.0.5" %}dockerhub2:10000/appname:4.0.5{% else %}dockerhub2:10000/appname3:3.0.14
{%  endif %}
    container_name: {{ dir }}
```

---

FWIW, you can simplify the template (and make the case easily extendible too)

```yaml
    image: {{ image[ver] }}
    container_name: {{ dir }}
```

if you put the data into the dictionary

```yaml
    image:
      '4.2': 'appname:4.2.0'
      '4.0.5': 'dockerhub2:10000/appname:4.0.5'
      default: 'dockerhub2:10000/appname3:3.0.14'
    ver: "{{ (version in image.keys())|ternary(version, 'default') }}"
```

---

Credit @mdaniel; the template below gives the same result

```yaml
    image: {{ image.get(version, image.get('default')) }}
    container_name: {{ dir }}
```

Comment: great minds think alike; I was going to suggest they switch to `{{ image.get(version, image.get('default')) }}` but the whole thing took more chars than the comment box allowed :-)

Comment: I've added your idea to the answer. Thank you!